# How can I define the precision of the array elements in python?

Tags: python, numpy

There is an array with large input elements named A. I want to define another array, named B, that its elements are obtained by the exponential of the negative of elements in A. I use the following code:
B=np.exp(-A)
The resulted elements in B are very small that in python they are shown equal to zero. How I can define the precision so that I don't get zero for the elements?

Thanks for your guidance in advance,
Zahra

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output data.

Comment: If there is more than 17-18 digits they're not going to be accurate anyway and this is due to how they are stored under the [IEEE-754 “double precision”](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#representation-error)

EDIT: link for python3.7 instead of 3.2

Answer (score 2):

You can try specifying the data type.

```
a = np.array([1000], dtype='f8') # 64-bit float
b = np.exp(-a)
b
>>> array([0.])

a = np.array([1000], dtype='f16') # 128 bit float
b = np.exp(-a)
b
>>> array([5.0759589e-435], dtype=float128)
```

Note the comment of @Plopp, depending on how large your values of `a` are this may not be enough

Comment: Thank you for your guide. I tried it but the elements' values are too large and based on @Ploppa's comment, putting dtype='f16' didn't work. Is there any other way?